# My pdf document is not loading in fpdf php file

Tags: php, fpdf

I have created a form using HTML(template.html) and linked it's submitting button to a PHP file (pdf.php). I have a pdf document 'Anbieterwechselauftrag MDDSL.pdf' attached in pdf.php file. when I press follow-up button in template.html, it does not load anything.

My task is to load the pdf document 'Anbieterwechselauftrag MDDSL.pdf' after pressing follow-up button.

Here is the Html part of the code

Template.html:

```
<form action="pdf.php" method="post">
   <input type="button" size="25" value="follow-up" /> 
</form>
```

Here is the pdf code that has the PDF document as shown below.

pdf.php:

```
<?php
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi2/src/autoload.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new Fpdi();
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the source file
$pdf->setSourceFile('Anbieterwechselauftrag MDDSL.pdf');
// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at position 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);

// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
$pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Someone kindly give me an idea/clue to go further. Thanks in advance